# How to create quad-sphere with evenly spaced edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh

On the left is a quad sphere which is the result of subdividing a cube, and using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to turn it into a sphere. On the right is my desired quad sphere, where I have painstakingly evened out the edges, so that all edges in the same edge loop are of the same length. What is the best/easiest/fastest way to create this kind of quad sphere?

[image]

My current method, which is rather tedious, looks like this:

I take one quadrant of one side of the original cube:
[image]

Then I alternate selecting all of the vertical and horizontal edge loops, and Looptools > Space them:
[image]

Finally, I duplicate and rotate this section of the sphere as necessary:
[image]

Is there a significantly more efficient way to achieve the same result?

This is a demonstration of the type of quadsphere I am attempting to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but are you sure what you're wanting is even possible?  Seems to me that any method is going to give you an approximation.  Isn't this somewhat related to the problem of projecting a map of the globe with limited distortion?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections

Comment: Yes, I am sure what I want is possible, because I have already created it. I'm just looking for a quicker way to do so. My ideal quadsphere still has distortion, but the key is that all edges **in the same edge loop** are of the same length. I added a demo blend file to the question.

Comment: What interests me, since you've already done this, and show this on the GIF, why do you need help with this? Isn't the fastest way to generate more such meshes to just save this one and duplicate or append in other projects? Do you ask because you want to learn modelling techniques or because your technique somehow doesn't work on more subdivided sphere or something like that? Also, your technique ends up with the sphere being less spherical, i.e. if you cast it to sphere, it will move some vertices (and again produce non-equal line lengths). This brings us back to Allen's question.

Answer (score 6):

The *Extra Objects* addon can create a quadsphere with even edges
Just enable it in *Preferences > Addons*

[image]

Comment: That quadsphere also doesn't have even edges, but it's certainly a much better result than the cube + alt shift s method.