# How to map a UV sphere with no distortion

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to make a procedural planet shader, and a major problem I'm having is distortion on spheres. If I use the UV texture coordinates, they always get compressed at the poles and stretched on the equator.

[image: Texture is compressed on the poles, and stretched on the equator]

I've tried messing with the UVs, but I always end up with some really obvious seams. I'm also not using a normal image texture setup, so I can't use the spherical texture option. I've also tried using a separate vector node and using the Z axis to change the scale of the texture, but I still can't get it right. Is there a way to UV map a sphere with little to no distortion? Or does anyone know of a node setup that could correct the scaling issue?

Comment: Could you describe what kind of shapes you're starting with?

Comment: I'm using an image texture of a crater, and randomizing their locations across the mesh. Since the position is randomized, I can't use the spherical projection option.

Comment: You could cut the UV sphere UVs in half, horizontally or you could use a Quad sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253219/how-to-create-quad-sphere-with-evenly-spaced-edges